# Python Print individal values out of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to print every value out of my numpy array 1 value at a time across each row column by column. I have some code like this at the moment.

```
col = 0
row = 0

for i in hillarray:

print('col', x, 'row', y, hillarray[col, row])

col = col + 1
if col == 1936:
    row = row + 1
    row == 0
```

I can get this code to print the values of the whole first row col by col. Its just getting it to restart again for the next row. I think the if part of the statement is wrong and therefore not moving to the next row resetting the value of col to 0 and then reporting the for loop again.

Comment: Try x=0 (x will become the int 0) instead of x==0 (test if x is equal to 0 = boolean)

Comment: what is the shape of your array

Comment: Your indentation is not valid python and ambiguous, `hillarray` is not defined. Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your array is two dimensional:

```
for i in range(len(hillarray)):
    m = hillarray[i]
    for j in range(len(m)):
        n = m[j]
        print(f'row {i} column {j} n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to loop through both rows and columns, like this:

```
for x in range(len(hillarray)):
    for y in range(len(hillarray[x])):
        print(f'row {x} col {y}: ', hillaray[x, y])
```